# Tagging EBS Volume in cloudformation Windows EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to tag the EBS volume when I create Windows EC2 instance using userData with PowerShell as specified below, but the tags are not getting added to the EBS volume attached to the Windows EC2 instance.

Can someone let me what is wrong in this.

```
               "UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            "<powershell>\n",
                            "try {\n",
                            "$AWS_AVAIL_ZONE=(invoke-RestMethod -uri 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone' -UseBasicParsing).Content\n ",
                            "$AWS_REGION=$AWS_AVAIL_ZONE.Substring(0,$AWS_AVAIL_ZONE.length-1)\n ",
                            "$AWS_INSTANCE_ID=(Invoke-RestMethod -uri 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id' -UseBasicParsing).Content\n ",
                            "Write-Output $AWS_INSTANCE_ID\n",
                            "$ROOT_VOLUME_IDS=((Get-EC2Instance -Region $AWS_REGION -InstanceId $AWS_INSTANCE_ID).Instances.BlockDeviceMappings | where-object DeviceName -match '/dev/sda1').Ebs.VolumeId\n ",
                            "$tag = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag\n ",
                            "$tag.key = \"Name\"\n ",
                            "$tag.value = \"MyVolume\"\n ",
                            "New-EC2Tag -Resource $ROOT_VOLUME_IDS -Region $AWS_REGION -Tag $tag\n",
                            "Write-Output $ROOT_VOLUME_IDS\n",
                            "}\n",
                            "catch {\n",
                            "Write-Output $PSItem\n",
                            "}\n",
                            "</powershell>\n"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            },
```

Comment: Check the logs C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log\UserdataExecution.log or C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Logs\Ec2Config.log on the instance. Update your question with the output. Your issue could be permissions - have you assigned IAM permission to allow `ec2:CreateTags` to be used by the instance profile? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html

Comment: Thanks @MisterSmith, Yes this looks like a permission issue.